# Pandas Merging and Converting Rows into Columns and feature engineering

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables like this,

Table A

```
ID_1   Value_1   Value_2
1      ABC       N_1
2      DEF       N_2
3      GHI       N_3
```

Table B

```
B_ID_1 B_Value_1     Value_2
1      abcd            N_1
1      abc             N_2
3      GHI_1           N_3
3      GHI_2           N_3
3      GHI_3           N_3
3      GHI_4           N_3
```

The number of records for a particular number occurs to be ID.
In this case, it is 4. But it changes everytime.
I want to do a Left Merge (From Table A to Table B) and then convert it to something like this.

```
ID_1   Value_1   Value_2     B_Value_1_1    B_Value_2_1  B_Value_1_2      B_Value_2_2     B_Value_1_3     B_Value_2_3    B_Value_1_4    B_Value_2_4        
1      ABC       N_1         abcd             N_1           abc          N_2
2      DEF       N_2
3      GHI       N_3         GHI_1            N_3          GHI_2         N_3                  GHI_3            N_3             GHI_4            N_3
```

And add two extra columns.

count_match is basically the checking of numberofmatches of Value_1 to B_Value_1_1 to B_value_1_4

numberofvaluesis basically the checking of numberofmatches present from B_Value_1_1 to B_value_1_4.

In this case, extra columns (count_match and numberofvalues) will look something like

```
ID_1  count_match numberofvalues
1      1               2   
2      0               0 
3      0               4
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve the expected result for the first part of your question, the second part should be straighforward after getting your data in the expected format.

**1. Pre-Process**

Preprocess Table B so that it has one row for each ID. You can do a `groupby` B_ID_1 and pass a function to flatten the groupes:

```
def flatten_group(x):
    n = len(x)
    vals = x.iloc[:,1:].values.flatten().reshape(1, -1)
    names = np.char.add(
        np.array(['B_Value_1_', 'B_Value_2_']*n),
        np.repeat(np.arange(1, n+1).astype(str), 2)
    )
    return pd.DataFrame(data=vals, columns=names)
```

```
b_prep = b.groupby('B_ID_1').apply(flatten_group).reset_index(level=0)
```

**2. Left Join**

Here you just do a left join

```
pd.merge(a,b_prep,how='left', left_on='ID_1', right_on='B_ID_1').drop('B_ID_1', axis=1)
```

---

**Details**

`b_prep`

```
   B_ID_1 B_Value_1_1 B_Value_2_1 B_Value_1_2 B_Value_2_2 B_Value_1_3  \
0       1        abcd         N_1         abc         N_2         NaN   
0       3       GHI_1         N_3       GHI_2         N_3       GHI_3   

  B_Value_2_3 B_Value_1_4 B_Value_2_4  
0         NaN         NaN         NaN  
0         N_3       GHI_4         N_3
```

`pd.merge`

```
   ID_1 Value_1 Value_2 B_Value_1_1 B_Value_2_1 B_Value_1_2 B_Value_2_2  \
0     1     ABC     N_1        abcd         N_1         abc         N_2   
1     2     DEF     N_2         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
2     3     GHI     N_3       GHI_1         N_3       GHI_2         N_3   

  B_Value_1_3 B_Value_2_3 B_Value_1_4 B_Value_2_4  
0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
1         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
2       GHI_3         N_3       GHI_4         N_3
```